# Erro ao carregar arquivo para lista encadeada

Tags: c, arquivo, lista-encadeada

Esse código carrega elementos de um arquivo .txt, porém aparentemente ele consegue carregar as informações do arquivo, mas dá algum erro na inserção da lista, mas não tô conseguindo identificar. Segue o código e as informações do arquivo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Cronograma {
    int data_cheg;
    char hora_cheg[50];
    char nome_navio[50];
    int carga_navio;
    struct Cronograma *prox;
};

typedef struct Cronograma cronograma;

void insere (cronograma *lista, int data, const char hora[], const char nome[], int carga) {
    cronograma *p, *novo;
    p = lista->prox;

    novo = malloc(sizeof(cronograma));
    novo->data_cheg = data;
    strcpy (novo->hora_cheg, hora);
    strcpy (novo->nome_navio, nome);
    novo->carga_navio = carga; 

    while (p->prox != NULL) 
        p = p->prox; 
    novo->prox = p->prox;
    p->prox = novo;
}

void carrega_arquivo (cronograma *lista) {
    cronograma *p = lista->prox;  
    FILE *f;
    int dc, c; char nv[50], hc[50];

    f = fopen ("crono.txt", "rt");

    if (f == NULL) {
        printf ("Problema na abertura do arquivo");
        return;
    }

    while (!feof(f)) {
        fscanf(f, "%d %s %[A-Z a-z] %d", &dc, hc, nv, &c); 
        printf("%d %s %s %d", dc, hc, nv, c);
        printf("\n");
        insere (p, dc, hc, nv, c);
    }
    fclose(f);
}

void imprime (cronograma *lista) {
    cronograma *p; 

    for (p = lista->prox; p != NULL; p = p->prox) {
        printf("%d %s %s %d", p->data_cheg, p->hora_cheg, p->nome_navio, p->carga_navio);
        printf("\n");
    }
} 

int main() {
    cronograma *Lista;
    Lista = malloc(sizeof(cronograma));
    Lista->prox = NULL;

    carrega_arquivo(Lista);

    return 0;
}


02 02:00 PANAMAX 80000
02 11:20 CAPE SIZE 180000 
03 04:00 HAND SIZE 50000 
03 12:00 SMALL CAPE SIZE 125000 
03 14:00 PANAMAX 80000 
04 09:30 HAND SIZE 50000 
04 09:30 CAPE SIZE 180000 
05 17:00 CAPE SIZE 180000 
05 19:00 CAPE SIZE 180000 
05 23:00 PANAMAX 80000 
06 06:00 PANAMAX 80000 
06 08:00 SMALL CAPE SIZE 125000 
06 15:00 HAND SIZE 50000 
06 16:00 HAND SIZE 50000 
08 02:00 CAPE SIZE 180000 
08 09:00 PANAMAX 80000 
09 10:00 SMALL CAPE SIZE 125000 
10 13:00 CAPE SIZE 180000 
10 14:00 19-HAND SIZE 50000 
10 19:00 CAPE SIZE 180000 
11 05:00 SMALL CAPE SIZE 125000 
11 10:00 PANAMAX 80000 
11 14:00 SMALL CAPE SIZE 125000 
12 13:00 CAPE SIZE 180000 
13 06:00 25-HAND SIZE 50000 
13 09:00 SMALL CAPE SIZE 125000 
14 15:00 PANAMAX 80000 
14 15:00 CAPE SIZE 180000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marcelo, Seu problema é bem simples.
na primeira linha da função carrega_arquivo, você atribui o valor lista->prox no ponteiro para cronograma, p.

`cronograma *p = lista->prox;`

fazendo com que p receba NULL. No caso você está passando o valor null atribuido na função main para p.

```
cronograma *Lista;
Lista = malloc(sizeof(cronograma));
Lista->prox = NULL;
```

assim quando você faz a chamada da função insere vc faz novamente, na segunda linha da função insere

`p = lista->prox;// (p = NULL->prox)`

Se na função carrega_arquivo você alterar a primeira linha para

`cronograma *p = lista;`

o programa roda normalmente.

Espero ter ajudado.